# Hibernate many to many cascade type issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am currently using Hibernate in a project and I am having trouble setting up a Many to Many relationship. I think my issue is related to the Cascade types.

The scenario is we have an advert and each advert can have many tags but each tag can be related to many adverts. The ManyToMany annotation of the advert entity is:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH })
@JoinTable(name = "adMediaAdvertiserTag",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "adMediaId") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "advertiserTagId") })
```

And the ManyToMany mapping on the tag entity is:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "advertiserTags", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
```

I am seeing two different errors depending on the configuration of the cascade types and if the tag already exists in the database.

If the cascade type on the advert doesn't include PERSIST and the tag doesn't already exist then we get this exception:

```
TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance
```

And if the cascade type on the advert does include PERSIST and the tag does already exist we get:

```
PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist
```

The only way I can get this working is not have PERSIST as a cascade type but loop through each tag and save them to the session.

Is this the correct approach? Is there a way that hibernate could automatically handle this for me?

Let me know if this isn't clear or you need any more information.

UPDATE

I am saving the objects using a service that uses the save method the CrudRepository object of the springframework. There is a lot of code so I can't really post it all.

I am currently not calling any merge or persist method for any object I am trying to save. I was under the impression Hibernate would handle that sort of thing for me.

Comment: So you are saying that some of the tags could already exist where as some of them are new and need to be persisted. If so, shouldn't it be a call to to `merge` instead of `persist` method?

Comment: Yes thats correct. I have tried that but when a new tag is added it returns TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance

Comment: Do you mean CascadeType or the method used to save the object?

Comment: I mean the method.

Comment: No I am not calling those. Have you seen the updates on the question? I am using the CrudRepository of the spring framework. I was under the assumption that the save method would handle merging and persisting under the hood. Do you know if thats true?

Comment: I guess that could be the problem. CrudRepository calls persist or save but not sure of the behavior with manytomany  ollection having a mix of it? It might be worth adding new method in crudrepo with query annotation that explicitly calls merge.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice. I'm in the process of researching the CrudRepository so hopefully that will lead to answers.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please add the code you are using to persist your Advert and Tag objects. I tested with the following code (which I believe similar to yours) and it works:

```
User user = new User();
Role role = new Role();
role.setId("TEST_ROLE");
user.getRoles().add(role);

entityManager.persist(user);

User user2 = new User();
user2.getRoles().add(role);
entityManager.persist(user2);
System.out.println(user2.getId());
```

in User I have:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = true)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false, updatable = true)})
protected List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
```

and in Role I have:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles")
protected List<User> users;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this was one of the scenarios I was explaining that didn't work for the scenario when we have an existing tag (or role in your case). I'll update the question with some more context.

Comment: I just noticed the call to the persist method, is this needed for each newly created object?

Comment: Yes, you need to make it to persist a new User, in this case, and the Role object will be persisted, indirectly because of the cascade.

Comment: Did you see my update? I was under the assumption that the CrudRepository of the spring framework would handle this for us when we call save?

Comment: I haven't used CrudRepository so not sure if it is related to your errors. Can you try persisting your objects with entityManager and see if it helps. If it does then you know what to investigate next. to get entityManager in your spring-annotated class you can do `@PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;`

Comment: `Role role = new Role()` is wrong. Role should be retrieved from the database: `role = roleRepository.findRoleByName("ROLE_USER");`